# Transferring an iOS App which used to use Passbook

Tags: ios, itunes, transfer, passbook

I have an iOS App which uses the Passbook entitlement. I now need to transfer the app to another account but Apple does not allow transfers of apps that use the Passbook entitlement.

From their documentation:

> No version of the app can use a Passbook entitlement.

I submitted a new version with Passbook disabled and I am sure that the Passbook entitlement is not registered for the newest version, which is now Ready For Sale, but I am still unable to transfer the app. I get the following message:

> You can only transfer apps that aren’t using Passbook IDs, certificates, or notifications.

Does this mean they do not allow transfers for apps which have used at least once this entitlement in the past?

Also, from that message, does "notifications" mean "Push Notifications"? My app does have the Push Notifications entitlement enabled. Is this the real cause for the message?

Is it possible to disable all of these things and be able to transfer the app? It is hard to test on trial and error because it would affect our production environment and the review wait times are too long to revert quickly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check again iTunesConnect [FAQ](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/da/jumpTo?page=faqs), [Transferring App Ownership](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/47.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.5.10.1)

> Why am I not able to transfer my app?
>
> You cannot transfer apps that contain or use:
>
> ...
>
> - Passbook entitlements in **any version** of the app
>
> ...
>
> To transfer any of these types of apps, the recipient must create the app as a new app. Current customers, ratings, and reviews cannot be transferred to the new app.

Comment: Almost 2 years since the question was asked, but it it might help someone:

In my case issue with Passbook was caused by **UrbanAirship** SDK: https://support.urbanairship.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208269623-Unable-to-transfer-app

Comment: @SergiiN. had the same issue few days back and it was Urban Airship :( :(

Comment: @dhaval yeah, I could do nothing about that unfortunately. The only way in this case is to create new app in AppStore and remove the old one.

Comment: If you're using **an sdk from a payment processor** (i.e we were using Reader sdk from Square), that's probably the reason you're seeing that error.